# generate call hierarchy graph with ctags

Tags: ctags, cscope, call-graph

Is there anyone who knows how to generate **call hierarchy graph** with **ctags** and **cscope**? I need to **run the commands in the terminal and redirect the output to a file**, rather than do it in vim.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cflow to do this. Just use it as:

```
cflow main.c
```